# Know of an interesting question or answer that Stack Exchange should tweet about?

Tags: discussion

Moderators have been asked to nominate content from any Stack Exchange site to be tweeted about from the [Stack Exchange Twitter account](https://twitter.com/StackExchange).

> We want to use the Twitter account to draw attention to a bunch of stuff but what we need your help with is:
>
> - **Awesome/interesting/fun Questions & Answers**
>     We'll feature a few of these per week and try to make sure that they're representative of a broad collection of our sites. This includes notable meta posts, too - though I'm guessing they'll be infrequent.
> - **Site events/contests**
>     If a site has a regular or one-off event, we may be able to tweet about some of them. Some of y'all do events throughout the year and we'd love to share some of the community-led fun.
> - **Users who do noteworthy work or meet celebratory rep levels**
>     *We won't Tweet about anyone without reaching out to them first*... but if there's someone you think deserves (and would appreciate) a spotlight on what they've been doing, either on main and/or meta, let us know.

If you have a suggestion for a question, answer or user that should be highlighted by the Stack Exchange twitter account, please suggest it below. Be sure to explain why you think it's noteworthy and interesting, which will help the Stack Exchange team draft the content of the tweet. If the moderation team agrees we will submit it.

My understanding is that the tweets are intended to get people from outside the Stack Exchange network interested in Stack Exchange in general (and ELL specifically) in the same way that Hot Network Questions get people already using the Stack Exchange network interested in ELL.

Did you know that there is also an [ELL Twitter account](https://twitter.com/StackEnglishLL)? The ELL account is a bit different because the tweets are from an automated system instead of curated by people. Following the ELL account may be a good way to find content you might not have seen otherwise. Tweets include things like ["featured" meta posts](https://twitter.com/StackEnglishLL/status/1105619625583280130), [bounties offered](https://twitter.com/StackEnglishLL/status/1105664929359630336), and [highly up-voted answers](https://twitter.com/StackEnglishLL/status/1105574328714842112).

Answer (score 4):

1. StoneyB's canonical post on the perfect aspect.

The most thorough explanation on the use and meaning of the present perfect that I ***have ever seen*** online and in any grammar book I possess for that matter, and I probably own about ten different levels of grammar books.

1. [Canonical Post #2: What is the perfect, and how should I use it?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it?rq=1)

One of @Listenever's best questions. I miss this user, at first glance their questions appeared to be rather banal but on closer inspection they were nearly always delightful gems.

2. [Why is "Mary told the cake to be cut by John" ungrammatical?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2828/why-is-mary-told-the-cake-to-be-cut-by-john-ungrammatical)

Comment: I have submitted both of these through the form. I’m not sure if I’ll get any feedback, or if they’ll just get tweeted out some day.

Comment: Some of the comments on the cake question are truly delightful.

Answer (score 2):

It's nowhere near my highest-upvoted question, and I'm not sure if it's "unsporting" to cite one of my own questions anyway, but I still find

> [Is “has or will read” grammatical?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121037/is-has-or-will-read-grammatical)

fascinating, over 5 years after having asked it. Perhaps because it turns on a *pronunciation* difference that would bother many people in speech, but which they [might not even notice](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121037/is-has-or-will-read-grammatical#comment248803_121037) in the written form.

Since the Twittersphere (most online user interaction, actually) is predominantly a ***written*** medium, there's a good case for saying things like this are more relevant today than they ever were in the past. I doubt it'll go viral, but you never know.

Comment: I *think* Colleen is especially interested in ELL posts, I could be mistaken. Why not post the request on EL&U?

Comment: Whoops! I didn't even *notice* that, despite the fact that I've probably interacted with Colleen more today than the whole of last year! Incidentally, as a (very well versed in English) nns yourself, do *you* think the "intriguing quirkiness" of the "non-homophonous" tension is equally striking when it's actually a foriegn language example? I've no idea if there's any equivalent in Italian - or even in French, which I do know at least a bit.

Comment: (I assume I'm right to expect the system will "ping" you for the above comment, since yours is the only username above it.)

Comment: Italian verbs can form the future without an auxiliary, so as far as I am aware, there is no similar problem e.g. "I read" *leggo* (present simple), *ho letto* (present perfect) *leggerò* (pure future). There wouldn't be any confusion or mind gymnastics

Comment: @Mari-LouA Actually the post from the CM Team made clear that we can submit things from any site, not just our own. They're looking for content suggestions, but not *too* many suggestions by opening up the submission process to all users :)

Comment: @ColleenV wouldn't it make sense that a moderator from ELL nominates posts that had been submitted to the site they moderate? That's how my brain works...maybe I'm slowly going senile. Eeek!

Comment: @Mari-LouA We were asked for our nominations  of content from any site, not to collect suggestions from our users, but we’re told we could ask our communities if we wanted to. Not every mod is going to ask on their sites I think, so I’m happy to pass on any suggestions from our community, not just ELL content.

Comment: I’ve submitted this through the form. Not sure if I’ll get notified of whether it has been “accepted” or not.